# Java do while, where char will accept uppercase and lowercase answer

Tags: java

How do you make the program accept `n` (lowercase) and `N` (uppercase) for the `while` condition?

```
char x;
int y = 1;
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
do {
  System.out.println(y);
  y++;
  System.out.println("Do you want to continue, Y/N? ");
  x = sc.next().charAt(0);
} while (x != 'N')
```

Comment: `x = sc.next().toUpperCase().charAt(0);`

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH!

Comment: or, you can check for both: while x != 'n' && x != 'N'

Comment: an alternative to above is `(x != 'N' && x != 'n')`

Comment: Hint: just putting your question title gave me existing answers immediately. Please remember that you are expected to do research prior posting questions. And rest assured: anything you can dream of asking **has** been asked before. And answered.

Answer (score -2):

use `Character.toLowerCase(x)!= 'n'`

Regards